# How compareTo() compares values in each iteration?

Tags: java, comparable

I know how compareTo() works *(i.e, 0,+1,-1)*. Below code works But I want to know how its comparing the objects in which order its comparing three objects.

**Note:** Searched previous qustions but didnt find any answer for this.

values insert into the list are **[a,c,b,d]**

could anyone please explain in which order its taking the above inputs for comparision.

when I debug I see below combinations of values for line `this.name.compareTo(employeeName.name);`

| this.name | employeeName.name |
| --- | --- |
| c | a |
| b | c |
| b (value repeats again) | c (value repeats again) |
| b | a |
| d | b |
| d | c |

```
package packageOne;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class W {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("a");
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("c");
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("b");
        Employee employee4 = new Employee("d");
        
        
        List<Employee> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(employee1);
        al.add(employee2);
        al.add(employee3);
        al.add(employee4);
        
        Collections.sort(al);
        
        System.out.println("after sorting");
        
        System.out.println(al);

        
    }

}
```

***Employee.java***

```
package packageOne;

public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    public String name;

    Employee(String nameEmp) {
        name = nameEmp;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employeeName) {

        return this.name.compareTo(employeeName.name);

    }
}
```

Comment: *FYI:* [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is not `(0,+1,-1)`, it is `(=0,>0,<0)`

Comment: If you follow the chain of calls inside `Collecions.sort` you'll find [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/fadf58043c10e4fd98dfdb35256f5efc6d3cd366/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java#L179) is the code that gets called. At least in openjdk. The documentation state that how sort works is an implementation detail.

Comment: The order of the comparisons depends on the implementation of `Collections.sort`. So for your purposes, you shouldn't care. As it happens, it's a [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Answer (score 6):

The order of comparison depends on the sorting algorithm used, which can differ depending on the Java version you're using. For instance, in Java 11 the sorting algorithm defaults to [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is a sorting algorithm derived from the more well-known merge sort and insertion sort algorithms.

Comment: Perhaps you know, but in case its not clear to those reading: the implementation has been timsort for a long time before Java 11 too. Java 7, I think

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how long it has been TimSort, I personally found out when using Java 8. I've been using Java since version 1.4, but I never bothered looking into the sort algorithm back then.

Comment: [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) says mergesort, [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) says timsort. In later versions, they removed all mention of the implementation. Rightfully so; it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Even so, it's an interesting piece of trivia. Thanks for looking this up!